# fuse utimensat problem

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, fuse

I am developing fuse fs at python (with fuse-python bindings). What method I need to implement that **touch** correctly work? At present I have next output:

```
$ touch m/My\ files/d3elete1.me 
touch: setting times of `m/My files/d3elete1.me': Invalid argument
```

File exists "d3elete1.me":

```
$ ls -l m/My\ files/d3elete1.me 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jul 28 15:28 m/My files/d3elete1.me
```

Also I was trying to trace system calls:

```
$ strace touch m/My\ files/d3elete1.me
...
open("m/My files/d3elete1.me", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)             = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
close(0)                                = 0
...
```

As you see **utimensat** failed. I was trying to implement empty **utimens** and **utime** but its are not even called.

Comment: Seems you have to implement `utimensat`...

Comment: I was trying and has no result. Here you can see fuse interface functions http://omake.metaprl.org/prerelease/omake-dll-fuse.html

Comment: I haven't found `utimensat` in the FUSE source code. Don't know what to do, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try launching fuse with the -f option. Fuse will stay in foreground and you can see errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks for this great hint! I don't know about it. It seems there is problem in fuse-python bindings - http://dumpz.org/21310/

Answer (score 1):

You must implement `utimens` and `getattr`. Not all the system calls necessarily map directly to the C calls you might be expecting. Many of them are used internally by FUSE to check and navigate your filesystem, depending on which FUSE options are set.

I believe in your case FUSE is preceding it's interpretation of `utimesat` to `utimens`, with a `getattr` check to verify that the requested file is present, and has the expected attributes.

### Update0

This is a great coincidence. There is a comment below suggestion that the issue likes with the fact that FUSE does not support `utimensat`. This is *not* the case. I had the exact same traceback you've provided while using fuse-python on Ubuntu 10.04. I poked around a little, it would appear that the fuse-python 0.2 bindings are for FUSE 2.6, it may be that a slight change has introduced this error (FUSE is now at version 2.8). My solution was to stop using fuse-python (the code is an ugly mess), and I found an alternate binding [fusepy](http://code.google.com/p/fusepy/). I've not looked back, and had no trouble since.

I highly recommend you take a look, your initialization code will be cleaner, and minimal changes are required to adapt to to the new binding. Best of all, it's only one module, and an easy read.

Comment: I have implemented getattr and utimens but utimens don't even is called during "touch" command. Here http://dumpz.org/21309/ is output of my debugger when I was running "touch".

Comment: The master branch of FUSE (the C library) doesn't contain the string `utimensat`. `utimensat` was standardized only in 2008; probably it's just too new to be implemented in FUSE.

Comment: Here http://dumpz.org/21310/ I had posted traceback. It is problems of fuse-python package ;(